# System Center Operations Manager (SCOM) 2007 R2: Send notification emails to a non-anonymous account

Tags: email, scom

I would like to send emails to an already established service account, but it's an account that requires a login name and password. I don't understand why SCOM only has two options: Anonymous and Windows Integrated.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Windows Integrated doesn't ask for credentials to log in with?

Comment: @Bart, it's not a windows account, it's just an email account.

Answer (score 1):

The Anonymous/Windows Integrated settings you refer to are in the email notification channel / add smtp server dialog. It is not asking for an email address; it's asking for an SMTP server to connect to.

Once you have set up a valid notification Channel, you enter the email address into a Subscriber object, then create a Subscription to link the two together, along with the conditions that trigger it.